# Is there no simple way to set WPF StatusBar text?

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, statusbar

I want to set the Text of a TextBlock in my StatusBar before making the user wait for a short moment while my program does a little bit of work.

Aparently, instead of doing a nice little function like this (which does not work):

```
Function Load(ByVal Id As Guid) As Thing
    Cursor = Cursors.Wait
    TextBlockStatus.Text = "Loading..."
    TextBlockStatus.UpdateLayout()
    Dim Found = From t In db.Thing _
                Where t.Id = Id _
                Select t
    TextBlockStatus.Text = String.Empty
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
    Return Found
End Function
```

I have to instead use this monstrosity:

```
Private WithEvents LoadWorker As BackgroundWorker

Private Sub Window1_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    InitializeLoadWorker()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeLoadWorker()
    LoadWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    LoadWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = False
    LoadWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = False
    AddHandler LoadWorker.DoWork, AddressOf LoadBackgroundWorker_DoWork
    AddHandler LoadWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf LoadBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted
End Sub

Sub Load(ByVal Id As Guid)
    Cursor = Cursors.Wait
    LoadWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Argument)
End Sub

Private Sub LoadBackgroundWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim Worker As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim Id As Guid = DirectCast(e.Argument, Guid)
    e.Result = From t In db.Thing _
               Where t.Id = Id _
               Select t
End Sub

Private Sub LoadBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    TextBlockStatus.Text = String.Empty
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
    Dim Found As Thing = DirectCast(e.Result, Thing)
    'now do something with the found thing here instead of where Load() is called.'
End Sub
```

And the Load() Function is now a Sub!!

There must be a better way to handle such a simple situation.  This doesn't need to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [Display Wait Screen in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616629/display-wait-screen-in-wpf).

The accepted answer has a way of doing what I think you want, without a Background worker class.

From the link in the answer to the other question, this might work for VB.NET (I haven't tried it though)

```
Public Sub AllowUIToUpdate()

    Dim frame As New DispatcherFrame()

    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, New DispatcherOperationCallback(AddressOf JunkMethod), frame)

    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame)

End Sub

Private Function JunkMethod(ByVal arg As Object) As Object

    DirectCast(arg, DispatcherFrame).Continue = False
    Return Nothing

End Function
```